# Need a more specific price calculation rule in Drupal Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

I have a price calculation rule like this:

**Event**: Calculating the sell price of a product

**Conditions**: Order contains products of particular product types AND User has roles

**Actions**: Multiply the unit price by some amount

Now, the problem is that when the cart contains products of the type that I selected as a condition AND the user has a specific role, the multiplication in the Action element is executed also on products of other product types. I only want to affect the prices of products with a specific type.

The cart can contain a mix of products of different types, but the rule should only affect the line items with the specific type.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your multiplication factor (I suppose you want to give a discount), you might want to try [Commerce discount](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount) which has support for discounts per order and discounts per product.

> Commerce Discount provides a new user interface for defining and
>   managing product and order level discounts. Using just the core
>   pricing system of Drupal Commerce requires knowledge of how to use the
>   Rules UI, which is beyond the capabilities of most merchants.
>   Additionally, the core system cannot support order level discounts or
>   certain types of shipping / product discounts. This module addresses
>   all of those things.

The role based discount condition is provided by [Commerce discount extra](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_discount_extra).